# Generate Azure KeyVault SecretIdentifier (Url) with Version

Tags: c#, azure, azure-keyvault

We are creating secrets dynamically in azure key vault and now we want to get Secret Identifier / Uri with version so that secrets can be retrieved ?

Is there any built in method or easy way to generate Secret Identifier ? Mainly I am getting challenge to retrieve secret version.

Sample : https://YourVaultName.vault.azure.net/keys/YourKeyName/01234567890123456789012345678901

We are using [keyvaultclient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.keyvault.keyvaultclient?view=azure-dotnet) C# class to manage keyVault in our application

[image: Screenshot contains secret identifier & version]

Comment: Not terribly clear what you are asking. There's an operation to list secrets, but if you are generating secrets why aren't you maintaining a separate database connecting them to whatever object needs them and then retrieving them by name? Key-vault isn't a great "database".

Comment: I need the keyvault url including key and secret version. I have added sample in the question.

Comment: I have the name of key/secret to retrieve but I dont have secret version which is part of url. Is secret version is required when we want to retrieve secret value ?

Comment: You can retrieve the latest version without specifying the version. Take a look at the key vault client class.

Comment: then what is the use of secret version ?

Comment: Typically you want the most recent version. BUT in a concurrent system another Azure app might be active and using the current version, you don't want to cause it to fail as you rotate the secrets. You can also set when the secret becomes valid or expires, e.g. I want to switch secrets at midnight - so you need two versions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200475/discussion-between-user2463514-and-ian-mercer).

Comment: I am still testing it, Will update once done. Thanks for followup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the current version of the secret, you could use [`GetSecretAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.keyvault.keyvaultclientextensions.getsecretasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_KeyVault_KeyVaultClientExtensions_GetSecretAsync_Microsoft_Azure_KeyVault_IKeyVaultClient_System_String_System_String_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) .

I use `Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication` to create a keyvault client, sample [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/service-to-service-authentication#using-the-library).

```
var azureServiceTokenProvider1 = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
var kv = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider1.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
var secret = kv.GetSecretAsync("https://<keyvault-name>.vault.azure.net/", "<secret-name>").GetAwaiter().GetResult(); 
Console.WriteLine(secret.SecretIdentifier.Version);
```

If you want to get all the versions of the secret, you could use [`GetSecretVersionsAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.keyvault.keyvaultclientextensions.getsecretversionsasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_KeyVault_KeyVaultClientExtensions_GetSecretVersionsAsync_Microsoft_Azure_KeyVault_IKeyVaultClient_System_String_System_String_System_Nullable_System_Int32__System_Threading_CancellationToken_).

```
var versions = kv.GetSecretVersionsAsync("https://<keyvault-name>.vault.azure.net/", "<secret-name>").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```